# Selenium Webdriver element returns None even with WebDriverWait

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a script using BeautifulSoup where I am trying to get the text within a `span` element.

```
number_of_pages = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'random})
print(number_of_pages.string)
```

and it returns a variable like `{{lastPage()}}` which means it is generated by JS. So, then I changed my script to use Selenium but it returns an element that doesn't contain the text I need. I tried a random website to see if it works there:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://hoshiikins.com/") #navigates to hoshiikins.com  
spanList= browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[13]/div/div[2]/div/p")      
print(spanList)
```

and what it returns is:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fe20e73e-5638-420e-a8a0-a8785153c157", element="3065d5b1-f8a6-4e46-9359-87386b4d1511")>]
```

I then thought it was an issue related to how fast the script runs. So, I added a delay/wait:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[13]/div/div[2]/div/p"))
)
```

I even tried different parts of the page and used a class and an ID but I am not getting any text back. Note that I had tried using the `spanList.getattribute('value')` or `spanList.text` but they return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue, your variable spanList is an web object, the find elements function doesn't return meaningful text. You have to do one more step and add .text to return the text. You can do this in the print statement

```
    print(spanText.text)
```

If this tag is an input element then you'll need

```
   print(spanText.get_attribute('value'))
```

This should print what you are looking for

Comment: In order to get that, the text must be a part of the list. That doesn't return anything at the moment. It returns an error.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I tried running it and basically just ran a for loop that iterates through the list.       for item in spanList: print(item.text)       it returned something, wasn't sure if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: I think I ll mark that as solved with that answer. My problem was different as I had used the text and get_attribute lines. But this is a good hint for someone who wants to get the text instead of the web object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're perhaps misunderstanding your results, the code you provided for Selenium works with one small change:

```py
driver.get("https://hoshiikins.com/")
spanList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[13]/div/div[2]/div/p")      
for span in spanList:
    print(span.text)
```

Returns `Indivdually Handcrafted with Love, Just for You.`

You're using `find_elements_by_xpath`, which is different from `find_element_by_xpath` as the former is plural (element**s**). So all you have to do is either change it to `element` or iterate over your result set and get the `text` property of the element.

Comment: It doesn't return that to me. It returns None. I had tried text or getattribute before

Comment: I tested it using both Chrome and Firefox, same result. Could you provide your current code that you're testing, including the URL of the website your testing against because your question makes me believe hoshiikins is just an example which could be the issue.

Comment: It is exactly the same code. I run it again and the result got returned. It then returned None again. Now it works again. I don't understand what would disrupt it. I have no addons on Firefox.

Comment: If it's taking a while to load for you, I'd suggest increasing your `WebDriverWait` from 10 seconds to, say, 30 and see if that make any effect. If so, it's likely just your machine/connection.

Comment: Interesting. My machine is strong and the connection is good. It works now. Solved :) Although I changed nothing.

Comment: Strange, glad it's solved! I hope my answer helped anyway.